# Is there a looping problem in my c program?

Tags: c

So I had this question that intrigued me:
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFlTX.jpg)

And I tried with it I really did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    int house_nmbr;
    int zip_code;
    char st_name[51];
    char country_name[51];
} ADDRESS;
typedef struct
{
    char name[51];
    ADDRESS billing, shipping;
} CLIENT;
ADDRESS READ_ADDRESS()
{
    ADDRESS *AD;
    printf("Enter the house      number.\n");
    scanf("%d", &AD->house_nmbr);
    printf("Enter the street name.\n");
    gets(AD->st_name);
    printf("Enter the zip code.\n");
    scanf("%d", &AD->zip_code);
    printf("Enter the country.\n");
    gets(AD->country_name);
    return *AD;
}
void READ_CLIENT(CLIENT *c)
{
    ADDRESS A1, A2;
    printf("Enter the following information about your billing address:\n");
    A1 = READ_ADDRESS();
    printf("Enter the following information about your shipping address:\n");
    A2 = READ_ADDRESS();
    printf("Enter your name,\n");
    gets(c->name);
    c->billing = A1;
    c->shipping = A2;
}
void FILL_CLIENTS(CLIENT C[50])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        READ_CLIENT(&C[i]);
}
void FIND_CLIENTS(CLIENT C[50], int d)
{
    int i;
    printf("The clients with this zip code: %d have the following:\n", d);
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (C[i].billing.zip_code == d || C[i].shipping.zip_code == d)
        {
            printf("Name: %s.", C[i].name);
            printf("Billing address:\tHouse number:%d\tStreet name:%s\tZip code:%d\tCountry:%s\t\n", C[i].billing.house_nmbr, C[i].billing.st_name, C[i].billing.zip_code, C[i].billing.country_name);
            printf("Shipping address:\tHouse number:%d\tStreet name:%s\tZip code:%d\tCountry:%s\t\n", C[i].shipping.house_nmbr, C[i].shipping.st_name, C[i].shipping.zip_code, C[i].shipping.country_name);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int d;
    CLIENT C[50];
    FILL_CLIENTS(C);
    printf("Enter the zip code you want to find the clients holding:\n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    FIND_CLIENTS(C, d);
    return 0;
}
```

However it showed me this error on the screen when I run it:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDB6W.jpg)

Is there a problem in the looping? Or is it in one of the functions?
Im mostly a beginner in functions so I think I’ve done it wrong somewhere? Maybe with the pointers or elsewhere

Comment: You should start by formatting your code. That's quite unreadable. Put in newlines between functions and type definitions. Use correct and consistent indentation. If a program does not work, the usual thing to do is to debug it. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `ADDRESS *AD;` That declares a pointer. It does not point to any valid memory and dereferencing it, e.g. `&AD->house_nmbr`, results in undefined behaviour. You need to allocate memory using `malloc` or similar function.

Answer (score 0):

In this part

```
ADDRESS *AD;
printf("Enter the house      number.\n");
 scanf("%d", &AD->house_nmbr);
```

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized non-static local variable `AD`, whose value is indeterminate.

In this case, you won't need to use pointer.

```
ADDRESS READ_ADDRESS(){
ADDRESS AD;
printf("Enter the house      number.\n");
 scanf("%d", &AD.house_nmbr);
 printf("Enter the street name.\n");
 gets(AD.st_name);
 printf("Enter the zip code.\n");
 scanf("%d", &AD.zip_code);
 printf("Enter the country.\n");
 gets(AD.country_name);
  return AD;
   }
```

Also your program will be more improved if you check return values of `scanf()` and stop using `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, deprecated at C99 and removed from C11.